# Jquery .addClass() prevents css transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In working to transition an image from grayscale to full color after a fixed time I encountered a problem with Jquery's interaction with CSS Transition and i'm not sure what the work around is supposed to be:

If I start out with the existing `#globecont img {` style and change the `.globefc` from a class to a `#globefc:hover` everything works fine. But when I use Jquery to apply it as a class after a delay - the "class" is added to the IMG properly, but no transition or change in the filter is occurring.

I have not yet tried using .trigger("hover") in place of .addClass() but regardless of if that works or not, can someone explain why this doesn't work as written?

[JS Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/q2seoqx9/)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
body {background-color:#000000;}
#globecont {position:relative; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align:center;}
#globecont img {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    transition: 3s;

}

.globefc {
    filter: grayscale(0%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: none;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="globecont"><img src="http://philanthropicsandbox.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Globe1.png" width="300" height="300" id="globe"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#globe').delay(500).addClass("globefc");

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: On a side note to any future readers: I realized after the fact that .delay() can't be used with addClass() as .delay() only applies to animation effects, it will have to be setTimeout() instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, `#globecont img` is a more specific selector then `.globefc`, meaning it overrides the style added by `.globefc`, even though it is further down the stylesheet.

You can fix this by making the second selector more specific:

```
#globe.globefc {
    filter: grayscale(0%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: none;
    }
```

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7f3eouqq/)

**Note:** In your html, you already had the class `.globefc` added to the image, so the jQuery didn't actually do anything. In the JSFiddle, I removed that class, since it is added 500ms later by the jQuery.

Comment: Thanks, didnt really think about CSS precedence playing a role here, but i get it now. Thanks! Will accept answer as soon as it lets me

Comment: @DMSJax you will run into these problems a lot if you use css :D one of the easiest ways to tell is to use the browsers inspector